# Why doesn't "using static" work for System.Reactive.Linq.Observable in C#

Tags: c#, system.reactive, using-directives

I have the following working code snippet in VS2017 c#7

```
using system.Reactive.Linq

var combine = Observable.CombineLatest(o1, o2, (v1,v2)=> (v1,v2));
```

I would like to do

```
using static System.Reactive.Linq.Observable
var combine = CombineLatest(o1, o2, (v1,v2)=> (v1,v2));
```

but I get the error that

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0411  The type arguments for method
>   '`Observable.CombineLatest<TSource>(params IObservable<TSource>[])`'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

which is strange as I thought that **using static** was just syntactic sugar. Can this be made to work?

Comment: isn't observable generic class ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: @EhsanSajjad No it is not. It is a static class with "Extensions methods". Extension methods may not be declared in generic classes.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the generic parameters?

Comment: Of course I could specify the generic parameters on CombineLatest but that would defeat the purpose of the excercise which is to make the code a bit tidier.

Comment: Odd - that signature in the error message (one generic parameter, one `params` parameter) doesn't seem to match the signature [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211991(v=vs.103).aspx) (three generic parameters, three parameters) Could there be some other classes in play here that reuse similar names?

Comment: the problem is that it is marked as an extension method. It is just not allowed.